# How to reposition content in no scroll iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, position

I have an iframe for a google chart which has too much spacing around it. I want to embed this in my page but crop it to get rid of the surrounding space.

I was trying to do this by setting the iframe with smaller `height` and `width` attributes but I cannot work out how to reposition the content within the iframe to center it.

Here is the iframe for the chart:

```
<iframe width="550" height="170" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r56MJc7DVUVSkQ-cYdonqdSGXh5x8nRum4dIGMN89j0/pubchart?oid=1407844401&amp;format=interactive" onload="window.frames['itunes'].scrollTo(250,250)">></iframe>
```

How do you reposition the content of an iframe in this way or is there a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the iframe in a div or something and position the iframe.
here the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
.wrapper{overflow:hidden;} 
.wrapper iframe{position:relative; left:-40px; top:-30px;}
```